# For loop to access dictionary

Tags: replace, key, swift, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary of type String:AnyObject, and I want to have it be type String:String.  How can I convert them with the same key to type string using a loop?  I would think I could figure it out, but Xcode 6 sourcekit keeps crashing whenever I put in a for loop for the dictionary.

PS. I'm writing this in Swift, not Obj-C.

Comment: What do you mean by "an NSDictionary of type String:AnyObject"? That doesn't make sense, you can't specialize `NSDictionary`, it's not a generic type.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

This way you can loop over the dictionary for `objects:AnyObject`:

```
let dict = ["A":1, "B":2, "C":3]
var string = ""
for object in dict.values {
    string += "\(object)"
}
// string = "312"
```

If you want to loop over just the keys change to `.keys` as in the following:

```
for key in dict.keys {
    string += key
}
// string = "CAB"
```

Finally to loop over both keys and values with a Tuple `(key, object)` :

```
let dict = ["A":1, "B":2, "C":3]
var string = ""
var sum = 0

for (key, object) in dict {
    string += key
    sum += object
}
// sum = 6
// string = "CAB"
```

Note: This works with Beta 3.